# Printing all the words in a trie in C

Tags: c, recursion, printing, printf, trie

I was trying to print the contents of a trie in C. However I'm not very sucessful. And also let me say right in the beginning that this something we are doing in school right now, and this is one exercise.

This is how my trie looks like:

```
struct node{
char letter;//holds the letter associated with that node
int count;//its count
struct node* child[26];//each node can have 26 children
};

struct trie{
struct node* root;
}
```

This print method has to traverse this trie and print the words in alphabetic order and the ones that have a count of 0 should not be printed.

I was thinking along recursion and this is what my code looks like:

```
void print(node* root){
char buffer[15];//array to store the letters
if(root==NULL){ return;}//if the root is null return
int i;
int index=0; //index for the buffer
int hasAChild=hasChild(root);
if(hasAChild!=0){//the root has children keep on goinf

    for(i=0;i<27;i++){//go thru all the children and if they have children call print                         recursively
       if(hasChild(root->child[i]){
         print(root->child[i]);
         }
       else{
          //if they have no more children add the letter to the buffer
          buffer[index++]=root->child[i]->letter;
        }
          //print the contents in the bufffer
       printf("%s: %d",root->child[i]->count);
  }
}
```

//function to determine if a node has children, if so it returns their number if not,returns 0

```
 int hasChild(root)
    {
  if(root==NULL){
        return 0;
       }

 int i;
 int count=0;
 for(i=0;i<27;i++){
       if(root->child[i]!=NULL){
                   count++;
       }
    }
   return count;
}
```

This is what it would look like

```
     root
ab'c'defghijklmn'o'pqr's''t'uvwxyz
  'o'           'p'   'o''o'-subtrie-> "contribute", "open", "source"
  'n'           'e'   'u'
  't'           'n'   'r'
  'r'                 'c'-subtrie->"contribute", "to", "open", 
  'i'                     
  'b'
  'u'
  't'
  'e'-subtrie-> "to", "open", "source"
```

So i'm only suppose to print the words that are formed, not the letters that do not form a word.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I assume `count` is the number of children? Also, is there any sort of ordering in the tree?

Comment: Hello, count is the number of occurrences of a particular letter.@SGM1

Comment: I would add 3 more parameters to your print function to add a print buffer, its corresponding malloc sized, and current size of the string. BTW are there spaces in the substrees? How do you keep track of how many letter are being used, 0 or 1 on it it's corresponding position?

Comment: There are no spaces in the subtrees and I have function that upon taking a file that populates this trie @SGM1

Comment: My main concern is how do you separate the words in the sub-tree, or do you have a dictionary to compare to? And how you know the children array is "empty". You can't be guaranteed to have a NULL filled array with malloc (you can with calloc). Just to make sure, "to" should be printed 3 times in your example, right?

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
struct list
{
  char *word;
  list *next;
};

void getWord(node *node, list *words, char *previous)
{
  int i;
  char *newWord;
  char *tmp;

  if (node == NULL)
  {
     if (previous == NULL)
       return;
     addBloc(words, previous);
  }
  if (node.count == 0)
     return;
  if (previous == NULL)
  {
    previous = malloc(2);
    previous[0] = node.letter;
    previous[1] = '\0';
  }
  else
  {
    tmp = malloc(strlen(previous) + 2);
    strcpy(tmp, previous);
    tmp[strlen(previous)] = node.letter;
    tmp[strlen(previous) + 1] = '\0';
    free(previous);
    previous = tmp;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 27; i++)
  {
     if (node.child[i] != NULL)
     {
       getWord(node.child[i], words, strdup(previous));
     }
  }
}
```

**To Do** :

- Call getWord with (node, NULL, NULL);
- Code function addBloc, who add a bloc into linked list words

**Explanation** :

The purpose is to go throught all child and build word. Then store word into linked list.

**Exemple** :

T and C is child of A

O is a child of T

I and U is a child of O

Algorithm will make

```
   - previous = 'A'
```

then call methods to T

```
   - previous = 'AT'
```

then call methods to O

```
   - previous = 'ATO'
```

then call methods to I

```
  - previous = 'ATOI'
  - STORE 'ATOI'
```

then call methods to U

```
  - previous = 'ATOU'
  - STORE 'ATOU'
```

then call methods to C

```
 - previous = 'AC'
 - STORE 'AC'
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this so far, I'm reading it right now. @RaNdoM_PoWneD

Comment: I believe this works fine, assuming that this is how you intended the tree to work.

Comment: I assume after it is in a linked list I will just need to print the contents of that list?

Comment: ow.. I miss understand you. Yes you can print the values :)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I will do next, I do appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm guessing the way I was thinking about it and compared to the linked list suggestion, the second would be more efficient